# How to automatically do an AJAX request for PHP script every day at certain time?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, date

I tried to write a code that would everyday at 23:00 make an AJAX request to this URL `{ url: "addCredits.php" }`. At this URL there is SQL code for adding +5 to the "Credit" column by using PHP. I want every user to receive +5 in their "Credit" column everyday.

I tried running the code below, but at 23:00, the user did not receive any credit.

```
<script>
function startTime() {

    // set time variables h=hour, m=minute, s=second
    var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();

    //check if 0's have to be added for better appearance. no logical use!
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    //display current time on the element with id="txt"
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    //check if its 23:00:00 ... if so call addCredits.php
      if(h == 23 && m == 00 && s == 00) {
        $.ajax({url: "addCredits.php"});
    }

    //restart this function every second to update the clock
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should definitely have a look at what cronjobs are and what they do. They will help you to make this work on the server-side instead of on the client-side (in the browser)

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems here.

1. Are you sure your users actually had this page and running at 23:00:00? It won't work if the page isn't open, obviously.
2. `getHours` (et al) give the time in the user's local time zone. Users in different time zones will have this condition true at different times.
3. The condition you're using -- `h == 23 && m == 00 && s == 00` -- will only be true if the timer fires between 23:00:00 and 23:00:01. Since you're using a 1000 millisecond timer, and JS timers aren't guaranteed to fire on the exact requested interval, it's possible that some users will end up "skipping" the condition if the timer fires at, say, 22:59:59.99 and 23:00:01.00.

Most importantly, though: **Using client-side logic for this is completely insecure.** Any user can request `addCredits.php` as many times as they want, whenever they want; the fact that it's normally requested through this Javascript won't stop them from running it other ways. If you want to give your users credits periodically, use a **server-side** scheduled task to do it.

Comment: What is "server-side" ? Please guide me @duskwuff